# Python: map dictionary keys with values from a list to create a new list using for loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to create a new dictionary by using a for loop so that the 1st code in the 'code' dictionary equals the 1st location in the list 'location'. Then I need it to loop so that the 2nd code matches with the 2nd location, etc. till the end of the list.

I'm currently using the code at the very bottom below which produces the output that I want, but it doesn't create a new dictionary. I appreciate any help! Thank you!

```
location = [
'In the canopy directly above our heads.',
"Between my 6 and 9 o'clock above.",
"Between my 9 and 12 o'clock above.",
"Between my 12 and 3 o'clock above.",
"Between my 3 and 6 o'clock above.",
"In a nest on the ground.",
"Right behind you."]


codes = {'111', '110', '101', '100', '011', '010', '001'}


for c, b in zip(codes, location):
   print(c, "=", b)
```

Comment: `codes` isn't a dictionary here. It is a set, which is unordered, so "the 1st code" (etc) isn't a  meaningful concept. You describe it in the title as "dictionary keys", but the intent is not clear here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your looking for:

```
location = [
'In the canopy directly above our heads.',
"Between my 6 and 9 o'clock above.",
"Between my 9 and 12 o'clock above.",
"Between my 12 and 3 o'clock above.",
"Between my 3 and 6 o'clock above.",
"In a nest on the ground.",
"Right behind you."]


codes = ['111', '110', '101', '100', '011', '010', '001']
my_dict = {}

for c, b in zip(codes, location):
    my_dict[c] = b
    print(c, "=", b)

print(my_dict)
```

Comment: This does nothing to address the fundamental problem in the question, that `codes` is an unordered collection (a set). There is no point in `zip`-ping it with a list. OP needs to sort this out before the question can be usefully answered. Or at least you need to discuss this in the answer.

Comment: Op mentioned that he gets the required output. So I believe that he just needs to make a dictionary.

Comment: He/she probably hasn't checked very carefully, to be honest. There is no point in constructing a dictionary in which the association between keys and values is totally arbitrary.

Comment: Raz thank you for your help. I tried your code and like Alaniwi said it doesn't come out ordered the way I want it because 'codes' is a set and not a dictionary. Is it possible to convert 'codes' to a list and then iterate through each item? I am new to python so thank you for understanding.

Comment: You mean the version which uses a list instead of a set?

Comment: yes if it's possible to use that set and then iterate through the values of the location in the order that the set is currently in, but Alaniwi is saying that is not possible.

Comment: @Newcoderpython I am not saying that it is not *possible* but that it is not *meaningful*. I see now that Raz Crimson has changed the answer to use a list instead. If you work with a list then this is fine, but as soon as you use any kind of set, the order in which you get the elements out when you iterate over it (as `zip` does) is arbitrary.

Comment: @Newcoderpython You can convert a set to a list just by doing `list(my_set)` but this will not recover the original insertion order from the set - that ordering is already lost. You can sort the list, but if you have a specific ordering that you want to be remembered, then you have to use an ordered collection (e.g. a list) from the start.

Comment: ok thank you guys! i understand now. i appreciate your help!